# viewDidLoad in an XCode Utility Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have some code that I want to run in a utility application whenever the main view is shown. I put the code in viewDidLoad, and it only runs when the program starts up. If I flip to the other view, and then flip back to the main view, the code doesn't run. So how can I get this code to run everytime the main view is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewWillAppear: or viewDidAppear: